# get strange character when using curl php

Tags: php, curl

I use curl in php to get data from a website and add to my mysql database.
But the string I get is formatted strange. i've tried some method but didn't help me. who used to deal with it please give me your solution.

My curl method here:

```
function grab_page($site){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
ob_start();
return curl_exec($ch);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close ($ch);
```

}

After get it, i echo the html, my method here:

```
    function getDetailPage(){
    $detailData = grab_page("https://www.deliverynow.vn/ho-chi-minh/hanuri-quan-an-han-quoc-xo-viet-nghe-tinh");
    echo  htmlspecialchars($detailData);
}
```

The html string i got is change to weird character like: `M&#243;n kh&#225;c` . But it should be like this: ***Món khác***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to restore characters.